# Laravel "Undefined variable" in blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I've seen many questions all over the web similar to this one, and tried all the suggestions but nothing worked, I'm not sure what I'm missing.
I just want to show all the products from my database on my home.blade.php view, and tried in many different ways but is always the same error.

So this is my function in the `HomeController`:

```
public function index()
    {
        $produtos = Produtos::all();
        return view('home', ['produtos' => $produtos]);
    }
```

And this is my web.php:

```
Route::get('home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

And finally the part of the home.blade.php view that i'm trying to use but isn't recognized:

```
@foreach($produtos as $produto)
                                         
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="">
             <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">{{$produto->nome}}</h4>
                     <p class="card-text">{{$produto->categoria}}</p>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
```

I've also tried doing like this:
HomeController:

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('home', function () {
    $produtos = DB::select('select * from produtos');
    return view('home', ['produtos' => $produtos]);
});
```

But the same error:

> Undefined variable "`$produtos`" appear.

Thanks!

Comment: Please try to print the $produtos useing var_dump($produtos); die; and check if the value exits.

Comment: Why not use `DB::table('produtos')->get();` or [Eloquent models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent)?

Comment: You are missing `use App\Produtos;` in top of your controller if you use `Produtos` model.  @Lucia

Comment: I already had the "use App\Models\Produtos" on top of my controller! Using the DB::table('produtos')->get(); also didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use route like this

Use `use App\Produtos;` In your top of controller.

*Write your route file code like.*

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

*Write in your controller file like*

```
use App\Models\Produtos;  // or use App\Produtos; 

public function index()
{
    $produtos = Produtos::get();
    return view('home',compact('produtos'));
}
```

**OR**

```
public function index()
{
    $produtos = \DB::table('produtos')->get();
    return view('home',compact('produtos'));
}
```

Comment: Hey Vikas! I tried all of this and still the same problem :/

Comment: can you share your table image and model code and databse table entry

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your help! The problem was actually something very simple that passed me by, I was accidently using the "return view('home');" in 2 different routes, that's why it wasn't recognizing the variable.

I fixed it by excluding the other one and just having like this on my web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $produtos = \DB::table('produtos')->get();
    return view('home', compact('produtos'));
});
```